# como cambiar div por otro javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo 3 **divs** cada uno con un identificador id el primer **div** no contiene nada y los otros dos un nombre y una imagen estoy tratando con una function que cuando pasen 10 segundos mover el div que esta en segundo lugar al primero y que cada uno cambie de color pero solo logro cambiar el color no logro posisionar el ultimo al primero osea remplasar el primer **div**  que esta vacio por el tercer div es decir el ultimo 
la idea es que cambie de posicion no se si me doy a entender aqui les dejo el codigo

```js
function cambiarPorOtro() {
//ejecutará la función siguiente a los diez segundos:
setTimeout("cambiarPorOtro2()",10000);

}

function cambiarPorOtro2() {

   first.innerHTML = capaVideo2.innerHTML;

       document.getElementById("capaVideo2").style.background="green" ;
       document.getElementById("capaVideo").style.background="grey" ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first"></div>




<a href="javascript:cambiarPorOtro2();">click para colocar a andy en primer lugar </a>

<div id="capaVideo" style="display:block; background:yellow; ">henrry<img src="avatar.png" width="60px" height="60px"></div>



<div id="capaVideo2" style="display:block; background:yellow; ">Andy<img src="avatar.png" width="60px" height="60px"></div>
```

Comment: Para obtener y cambiar el contenido HTML de un div debes de llamar a su propiedad innerHTML. En este caso para añadir el contenido del div capaVideo2 a first puedes hacer: `first.innerHTML = capaVideo2.innerHTML;`

Comment: hey gracias funciona  pero lo que hace es una copia del tercero osea se posisiona en el primero pero se queda otro en el tercero yo quiero que se mueva arriva checa mi codigo  y ejecutalo ya lo edite edite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo los 3 divs: first, capaVideo y capaVideo2. Para pasar el contenido del último div al primero tienes que hacer usar innerHTML:

```
first.innerHTML = capaVideo2.innerHTML;//Pasa el contenido arriba
capaVideo2.innerHTML = "";//Borra el contenido del último div
```

Comment: gracias man totalmente funcional un heroe sin capa thanks!!!